# Ruby - Creating local database and checking if rows already exist

Tags: sql, ruby, sqlite, sequel

I am using "sequel" and "sqlite3" gems.

I created a local database with

```
DB.create_table :numbers do
  primary_key :id
  String :important_number
end
```

I have a list of numbers that are inserted into the database everyday, but before the insert, I need to somehow check if the records already exists in the database or not.

Inserting to database with

```
numbersFromAFile = Some Code
DB[:numbers].insert(:important_number => numbersFromAFile)
```

No problems with inserting, but now I need an `if` statement or something else to check if the `important_number` already exists.

So something like

```
if !DB[:numbers][:important_number] == numbersFromAFile
  DB[:numbers].insert(:important_number => numbersFromAFile)
else
  # do something else...
end
```

EDIT: added unique index

```
DB.create_table? :numbers do
  String :important_number, unique: true
end
```

and using

```
  if DB[:numbers].insert_conflict.insert(:important_number => numbersFromFile)
    DO SOMETHING
  else
    DO SOMETHING ELSE
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite3 supports various conflict resolution methods in INSERT which you can leverage from the sequel gem.

For these methods to work, it is necessary that you define proper uniqueness constraints in your database schema in a way that a "duplicate" `INSERT` would result in a uniqueness constraint violation. From your example, you could define a unique index in your `important_number` column.

With this index in place, you can instruct SQLite to ignore an insert if it would result in such a violation by using an `INSERT OR IGNORE ...` statement.

With sequel, you can emit such a statement with:

```
DB[:numbers].insert_conflict.insert(:important_number => numbersFromAFile)
```

See [the documentation](https://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc-adapters/classes/Sequel/SQLite/DatasetMethods.html#method-i-insert_conflict) on `insert_conflict` for additional options on how to handle conflicts (such as e.g. updating the existing record instead).

`insert` will either return the auto-generated ID if a new row was inserted or `nil` if nothing was inserted. You can thus implement your alternative action as:

```
unless DB[:numbers].insert_conflict.insert(:important_number => numbersFromAFile)
  # do something else...
end
```

Comment: This works just fine and answers the question, but 
how would you make an ```if else``` statement out of that? Because I am going to need the "else" part as well. If the number exists then do something else.

Comment: Hey, so your ```unless``` code doesn't return ```nil```, it returns "0" (zero) if there is nothing to insert.